# Drag and drop disabled

Tags: drag-and-drop

On chromium browser when I copy a phone number from other application and do <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and paste phone number inside that box then try to drag phone number and paste inside on another website box it's not get pasted. Suddenly this happened.

I restarted system and updated browser. Still same problem.

Comment: Please provide your OS & release details; some releases used `chromium` packaged as *deb*, others as *snap* and currently we have no clue as to which is default for your *unstated* OS & release, nor if you've made changes (which you should tell us about).  What is the other app?

Comment: Did you *very recently* file a bug on this issue?  If not you're likely not alone.. but it maybe very different as you didn't provide specifics as to release, package etc.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS . I filed the bug on this issue yesterday.  - @guiverc

Comment: You didn't provide package details; 18.04 defaults to *deb* package (the bug I was mentioning/thinking-of was for *snap* package though if it's in the chromium source - it'll be the same issue occurring on both package types which is very useful knowledge IF details were fully know; alas you didn't provide package type).

Comment: I don't know how to fetch package details. And also Chrome tab jump out of browser. When I I try to merge tabs to browser it's not working.